# Why is it always bad practice to skip calling the cancel function for a child context?

Tags: go, go-context

##### Problem Description

When using the "context" package in Go, the `go vet` command's "lostcancel" check will give a warning if you don't call the cancel function returned by context.WithCancel(). e.g. if you have:

```
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    foo(ctx)
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

...then Go vet would give you the warning:

> the cancel function is not used on all paths (possible context leak)

This is also mentioned in the Context package's documentation:

> Failing to call the CancelFunc leaks the child and its children until the parent is canceled or the timer fires. The go vet tool checks that CancelFuncs are used on all control-flow paths.

My issue is this: in at least one instance, I don't see why the cancel function should have to be called. Suppose I want to derive a child context so that I have the option to either:

1. stop downstream goroutines using the child context before the parent is canceled, such as upon encountering an early error, or
2. wait until the parent context is canceled, letting the child context live as long as the parent.

This seems to me to be a very natural use-case of the context package's parent/child tree structure. But this gives the same `go vet` error as mentioned above, because in the code execution path representing the second option (letting the child live for the same duration as the parent), the child context's cancel function wouldn't be called.

So, is this truly a shortcoming of `go vet`/the Go community's guidelines for using Context, or is there a flaw in my thinking about this topic?

##### Example Program

Here is a sample program where the error occurs. Go vet would give the warning for the line `barctx, barcancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)`. This example is obviously silly, because I could just check `bar` for an error *before* starting up its goroutine. But suffice it to say: in my actual program, this would not be an option.

```
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    foo(ctx)
    cancel()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("done")
}

func foo(ctx context.Context) {
    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        fmt.Println("foo done")
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        barctx, barcancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
        err := bar(barctx, i)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("bar error; canceled")
            barcancel()
        }
    }
}

func bar(ctx context.Context, x int) (err error) {
    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        fmt.Printf("bar done; x=%d\n", x)
    }()

    if x > 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("bar error")
    }
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `go vet` would be correct to return a warning. The problem specifically lies in the `bar` function. When you create it, `bar` creates a goroutine that blocks until `barcancel` or `cancel` is called. Until then, it will continue to exist. Therefore, it is imperative that you call the cancel function so that resources waiting for the context to be done can go out of scope and be garbage-collected.

To be clear, in your example, all the deferred routines will be cancelled because you cancelled `ctx`, which also cancelled every instance of `barctx`.  However, you shouldn't depend on this as you might not have control over whether or not the parent context will be cancelled. So, your function should take responsibility for the contexts it creates and uses in function invocations.

To be clear, you should modify your example code like this:

```
barctx, barcancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
err := bar(barctx, i)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("bar error; canceled")
}

barcancel()
```

Comment: But in this example, I don't want the goroutine in `bar()` to be canceled unless it returns an error. Like I said, I want it to live as long as the parent. It's true that I make the assumption that I have control over the parent, but that's also true in this case. It could be true in many cases. Go vet could clearly see it's true.  But I take your point anyway, I guess I'm just not using context how its meant to be used.

Comment: @tbell5 I see your point. In your example, are you trying to create a set-and-forget function that only cancels when an error occurs or the parent context cancels?

Comment: "When you create it, bar creates a goroutine that blocks until barcancel is called. Until then, it will continue to exist, even if your main function exits." This is wrong.

Comment: @Woody1193 Yes, that's correct. But I'm seeing now that I'm not using the child context as intended. I think I just have some poorly designed code, and should probably just refactor it.

Comment: @Volker After further study, I see you are correct. Thanks for enlightening me